# UITextView contentInset not working in UITextView on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

I'm trying to set a `UITextView`'s `contentInset` property. When doing so, the `UIEdgeInset`'s `top` variable works just fine. So `[self.textView setContentInset: 'UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)];` works.

But assigning any other variable of UIEdgeInsets doesn't work. Only the `top` adjusts. `bottom` doesn't adjust, neither do `left` or `right`.

So `[self.textView setContentInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 100, 50)];` doesn't do anything to my textView.

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, still no solution.

Comment: Still no solution? I am having the same problem in the iPad with the TextView getting covered up by the keyboard...

Comment: I've given up contentInsets since it seems to be a bug on Apple's part. I suggest those with similar problems to try and take advantage of adjusting contentOffset to try and replicate what you would originally do with insets.

Comment: Do you have any layout constraints that would override the expected behaviour at the bottom of the field ?

Answer (score 13):

Use setTextContainerInset instead of contentInset on iOS 7.

```
[self.textView  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 100, 50)];
```