# Problems 'Resizing' UITextView when the Keyboard is Shown, in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextview

I'm targeting iOS7 only.

I want to 'resize' a `UITextView` when the keyboard is shown, so that all of the text can be seen, rather than being hidden behind the keyboard.

I've considered a few different approaches to this...

**1) Change the frame of the `UITextView` when the keyboard shows.**

The following question details the same problem that I have with this approach - despite the frame being set correctly, the last line/cursor will extend beyond the bounds of the `UITextView`, and therefore be out of sight:

[UITextView cursor below frame when changing frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431684/uitextview-cursor-below-frame-when-changing-frame/18585788#18585788)

You can see this effect from the following screen shot. The `UITextView` has a green background. It's been added to a `UIView` with a red background. The arrow shows where the cursor is...

[image]

**2) Changing the `contentInset` property on the `UITextView`**

I believe that this recommended/preferred approach. Note, I've read the Apple documentation for resizing views based on the keyboard appearing/disappearing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

With my code, I'm getting no effect when I change the bottom component of the `UIEdgeInsets`.

Same example as above, green `UITextView` on a red `UIView`, the text disappears underneath the keyboard:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets insets = _textView.contentInset;
    insets.bottom += keyboardSize.height;
    _textView.contentInset = insets;
    _textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
}
```

**Note**: the `scrollIndicatorInsets` part **works fine**. It's hard to depict with a screen shot, but the scroll indicator starts and stops at the right place and appears to be the correct size.

I've read a bunch of questions where people have had a similar problem.

**3) Changing the `textContainerInset` on the `UITextView`**

The answer on this question suggests using `textContainerInset` instead of `contentInset` on iOS 7:

[UITextView contentInset not working in UITextView on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203486/uitextview-contentinset-not-working-in-uitextview-on-ios-7)

I've tried this also, but still don't manage to resize the `UITextView`.

In this question, 'mann' is also having problems with both the `contentInset` and the `textContainerInset`:

[UITextView content Inset Bottom not working iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407136/uitextview-content-inset-bottom-not-working-ios7)

**Questions**

- which is the correct/preferred approach, `textContainerInset` or `contentInset`?
- in the code shown above for setting the `contentInset`, am I missing something? Is there something else I need to set?
- are these bugs with iOS 7?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of begin? Begin might not represent the final size correctly, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem isn't the keyboard size. Checking that I can see that it's correct. I've read from others that UITextView is buggy with iOS 7... From my use, it seems that a bug is the cause of approach (1) above. As for approaches (2) and (3)  I'm not sure I'm understanding/using the APIs correctly. 7.1 is still in beta; not sure we can talk about that (yet).

Comment: So what about resizing the frame of the UITextView instead of its insets? You could convert the frame of the keyboard to the super view of the UITextView and do a intersection to see how much you should resize the view. I've done this with success in a few projects before.

Comment: Yep, I'm going to go for resizing the frame instead of the insets. I'm hoping that 7.1 is going to improve the situation with the cursor. I've read other workarounds relating to changing the colour of the cursor, so I will give that a try. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in iOS 7. Pete Stenberger solved this with a subclass of UITextView. You can find it here:

https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFTextView

Here's more info:

http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/fixing-uitextview-on-ios-7/