# UITextView contentInset is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

I'm displaying text inside UITextView. I need to apply some padding to text. When i use value for top position it's working. If i use value for other position it's not working.

```
 txtt_bgImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"txtt_bg_ipad.png"];
                  txtt_bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:txtt_bgImage];

          txtt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 300, 400, 250)];

          txtt.text=productDescription;



                  [txtt  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:15]];

                  txtt.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

                  [txtt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


                  txtt.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,0,0,0);

                //  [txtt  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 0, 0)];

                  txtt_bgImageView.frame=CGRectMake(170, 300, 400, 250);


                  [self.view addSubview:txtt_bgImageView];

                  txtt.editable=NO;

          NSLog(@"text is %@",txtt.text);

                   object.object_screentext = txtt;

          [self.view addSubview:txtt];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView contentInset not working in UITextView on iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203486/uitextview-contentinset-not-working-in-uitextview-on-ios-7)

Comment: I'm not using iOS7. I referred that question already it's not working

Answer (score 6):

For iOS7 use `textContainerInset`

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets textContainerInset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

For  Bellow iOS7 use `contentInset` and setting `UIEdgeInsetsMake` as bellow syntax.

```
UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right) {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {top, left, bottom, right};
    return insets;
}
```

According to your code you are setting only top side inset But if you wish to set all side you have to set content inset like bellow :-

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
       _TxtViewSummary.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);
    } else {
       _TxtViewSummary.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
```

That look like this:-

[image]

Comment: i already mention that used for ios7 with Xcode5 if you are still working with old one use `_TxtViewSummary.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);`

Comment: I'm using iOS6.1 then why contentInset is not working

Comment: at my end that working code check that IBOutlate or textviewl connect correctly or not.

Comment: I'm not using IBOutlet. I'm using code what i asking in question

Comment: txtt.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,0,0,0); that put only top side space not left or right sir replce with (10, 0, 10, 0)

Comment: (10, 10, 10, 10) put this first 10 for top second for left third for bottom and forth for right.

Comment: If i use negative value like -20 it's working with reverse. why it's not working in positive value?

Answer (score 3):

`textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 14, left: 16, bottom: 14, right: 16)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
[txtt  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 0, 0)];
```

Also, the right way to position element is in `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: No visible @Interface 'UITextView' declares the selector setTextContainerInset

Comment: This is for iOS7.prior to iOS 7 versions you need to use contentInset.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is the following:

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 740.0, left: 0, bottom: 20.0, right: 0)
self.textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -740)
```

I was getting an unwanted behaviour where `textContentInset` was placing the text properly to begin with, but then the content would scroll off screen.